# jQuery if grouped checkbox checked change parent

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox, parent-child

I'm trying to get the parent checked of a list of checkboxes to change as soon as a checkbox is checked. See my set up in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XWQcZ/95/

What I need is the blue square (a span) to change color as soon as 1 or more checkbox/radio buttons are  checked. It must change back if none is checked or (to make it more complex) if the Reset checkbox is checked. The 'Reset' checkbox does reset all checkboxes in the list.

So in simple words there must be something like:

```
 if ('#box input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
     var header = $(this).closest('#header span');
        $header.addClass('green');
    }
```

I'm not sure how to get the right parent div in jQuery and change it's color. Probably by adding a class and give that a color in CSS. How to do this exactly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about the radio button?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QbtTe/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Well.. it get's green indeed. However the other functions are not working anymore, and they were working fine. I need the same for the radio buttons indeed.